# How to extract static messages from templates into translation files?

Tags: templating, localization

I use Craft on multilingual site and I'm having some difficulty in getting the static messages on templates added or changed on every translation file I have.

Is there any way to extract those static messages changed or not already translated from templates into all translation files?

I'm looking for a functionality like of "yiic message" which searches for messages to be translated in the specified source files and compiles them into PHP arrays as message source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

For Craft 3, we use the Yii 2 Inspections plugin for PhpStorm to do this now. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9400-yii2-inspections

There is a translation inspection that will let you know which strings are missing translations and which translations are no longer in use.

---

**Old:**

We currently have our own command line tool that goes through all of Craft's files and extracts anything in `Craft::t()` (for PHP), and `|t` (for Twig) and `Craft.t()` for JavaScript.

What we would probably do is make that tool into a `yiic` command and update it to let plugins take advantage of it for their own files as well.

Will add it to the list.

Comment: is there a chance that you are going to share that cli with the rest of the world?

Comment: Updated answer @PeterPiper

Answer (score 3):

The [Translate plugin](https://github.com/boboldehampsink/translate) does what you need, it scans templates and plugins, and also provides an interface for translation.

Comment: unfortunately the translate plugin isn't maintained anymore.